# Realm Model Conversion Failed

Tags: swift, realm

I have a realm db model like:

```
import RealmSwift

class User: Object {

    let isVerified = RealmOptional<Bool>()   
    @objc dynamic var pk = 0
    @objc dynamic var profilePicUrl: String? = nil
}
```

And I am getting data from service and it returns same name and type like realm model.

I want to save this data to db. But when I try to convert model to `realm model` it gives error.

```
let data = [Users(value: serviceUser)] -> serviceUser comes from service.
```

Before save when I try to convert I get this error:

> 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value 'ServiceUserModel(isVerified: Optional(false), pk: Optional(123456), profilePicUrl: Optional("") of type '__UserDataValue' for 'bool' property 'Users.isVerified'.'

serviceUser Model:

```
public struct ServiceUserModel: Codable {
    public var isVerified: Bool?    
    public var pk: Int?
    public var profilePicUrl: String?
}
```

I do not want to use `for` loop because of performance problem. I want to save this data in one time.

Save Method:

```
func save(users: [Users]){

        try! database.write {
            database.add(users)
        }
    }
```

How can I convert it?

Comment: You've got the pk var defined as an optional in the ServiceUserModel but it's not optional in your Realm object User.

Comment: You also mentioned saving data using a for loop and performance issues. Can you include code as to what that means and also what type of performance issues you're having?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is located here:

> when I try to convert

When dealing with RealmOptional you have to set it's `.value` property.

`let isVerified = RealmOptional<Bool>()`
now the isVerified.value is nil

`isVerified.value = true`
now it's true

But you can't use the `Bool?` to set the value.

The same applies to `pk`.

You should implement the `convenience init()` and provide some default values for your optionals

Comment: But in this way I need for loop to insert data in db. Am I wrong? Is there any way to insert data without any loop?

Comment: you can use the `.map`: `let realmUsers = serviceUsers.map { User(withServiceStruct...) } `